# Issue in Restart the app in open-shift

Tags: openshift

I have deploy my app to open-shift now it is showing the **status:building** when i run my aplication is shows **Service Temporarily Unavailable** .

While Restarting my application it is giving the issue

```
 Unable to complete the requested operation. 

  Restarting PHP 5.3 cartridge (Apache+mod_php) 
  Application directory "/" selected as DocumentRoot 
  Starting PHP 5.3 cartridge (Apache+mod_php) 
  Application directory "/" selected as DocumentRoot 

  Starting MySQL 5.5 cartridge 
  MySQL server failed to start: 

   Error writing to temporary file 
   cat: /var/lib/openshift/533b9da2500446e28d00089d/app-root/logs//mysql.log: No such file or directory

   Warning: Gear 533b9da2500446e28d00089d is using 100.0% of disk quota
   Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/533b9da2500446e28d00089d/php 
   Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/533b9da2500446e28d00089d/mysql
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... obviously it is out of space. Try these:

```
rhc app tidy -a <appname>
rhc cartridge storage <cartridge> -a <appname> --add 6
```